# Why can I only load local resources for my index file?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, server

I am hosting a server with nodejs, and have created a login, signup and menu. My login looks like this:
[image]

While my signup looks like this:

[image]

This is a snippet of my code:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views')));

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/users/signup', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup');
});
```

Why will the CSS not load for signup, but will for login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using relative paths instead of absolute paths. try replacing your 'views/view.css' with '/views/view.css' in your html file.

Comment: Thank you my friend!